# Devise route helpers inside namespace - problem with warden.authenticate!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, devise, warden

I have problem with logging to my application through API. I want to authenticate user through POST /api/v1/users/sign_in and return this user's object if email with password are valid.

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users
...
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    devise_scope :user do
      post 'users' => 'registrations#create', :as => 'user_registration'
      post 'users/sign_in' => 'sessions#create', :as => 'user_session'
    end
  end
end
```

**controllers/api/v1/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => 'api/v1/sessions#failure')
    render :json => resource
  end

  def failure
    render :text => 'not good', :status => 401
  end
end
```

Problem is that user is never authenticated. It is not even selected from database. This is my local server log:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Jul 12 11:46:55 +0200 2011
  SQL (0.6ms)  SHOW TABLES
  Processing by Api::V1::SessionsController#create as 
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"my_email@example.com"}}
Completed   in 1ms
  Processing by Api::V1::SessionsController#failure as 
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"my_email@example.com"}}
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
```

I have already tried to use `:scope => :api_v1_user` and then giving POST data for `user_v1_api`, but this did not help. Sever log looks exactly like this one above.

Email and password are definitely correct, because when I change path from `/api/vi/users/sign_in` to `/users/sign_in` everything is ok and I'm logged in.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that you haven't added your session controller to devise controllers in routes. For a standard implementation of custom devise controllers it is done in the devise_for statement in the routes as:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "user/sessions" }
```

I am not sure about the namespaced one for your API. I don't know if it is the best way to do it but maybe you can try:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "api/v1/user/sessions" }
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Is your failure method ever being called an a failure?

For the heck of it, change the 'api/v1/sessions#failure' to ':failure' when you call warden.authenticate! and see if the login is successful.

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer for this question:

```
devise_for :admins, :class_name => "User"
```

Original post is here at the [Devise Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/plataformatec-devise/CiJtVkKp_7Y). This then lead me to the place I should have looked first the [API Docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3adevise_for). lol

Hope this helps!